# creating and accessing dynamic column names within dplyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rlang, tidyeval

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

example = tibble(
  date = today() + c(1:6),
  foo = rnorm(6), 
)

do.some.stuff <- function(data, foo.col){
  sum.col = parse_expr(paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "sum", sep="."))
  max.col = parse_expr(paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "max", sep="."))
  cnt.col = parse_expr(paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "cnt", sep="."))
  
  select(data, date, {{ foo.col }}) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na({{ foo.col }})) %>% mutate(
      "{{ foo.col }}.cnt" := cumsum( !is.na({{ foo.col }}) ),
      "{{ foo.col }}.sum" := cumsum({{ foo.col }}),
      "{{ foo.col }}.max" := cummax( {{ sum.col }} ),
      "{{ foo.col }}.mu" :=  {{ sum.col }} / {{ cnt.col }}
    )
}

do.some.stuff(example, foo)
```

So the above code works just fine, but it is kind of ugly, particularly the three `parse_expr` lines. i could rewrite the function as:

```
do.some.stuff <- function(data, foo.col){
  sum.col = paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "sum", sep=".")
  max.col = paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "max", sep=".")
  cnt.col = paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "cnt", sep=".")
  
  select(data, date, {{ foo.col }}) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na({{ foo.col }})) %>% mutate(
      cnt.col := cumsum( !is.na({{ foo.col }}) ),
      sum.col := cumsum({{ foo.col }}),
      max.col := cummax( {{ parse_expr(sum.col) }} ),
      "{{ foo.col }}.mu" :=  {{ parse_expr(sum.col) }} / {{ parse_expr(cnt.col) }}
    )
}
```

But it's not a lot better. Is there any other ways to do accomplish this same behavior (I don't want to change the shape of the df, that part is not up to me) but kick the rlang dependency? This works just fine for now but I would like something cleaner / easier to read if it is possible. If it wasn't obvious, I am newish to metaprogramming in R although I do have experience in other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `across` with the `.names` argument or if foo_cnt, etc. with an underscore is ok then just omit the `.names` argument since that is the default.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

do.some.stuff.2 <- function(data, col) {
  cnt <- function(x) cumsum(!is.na(x))
  mx <- function(x) cummax(cumsum(x))      
  mu <- function(x) cumsum(x) / cnt(x)
  data %>%
    select(date, {{col}}) %>%
    filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na({{col}})) %>%
    mutate(across({{col}}, lst(cnt, sum=cumsum, max=mx, mu), .names = "{.col}.{.fn}" ))
}
# test
do.some.stuff.2(example, foo)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  date             foo foo.cnt   foo.sum   foo.max    foo.mu
  <date>         <dbl>   <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2021-02-11 -0.000202       1 -0.000202 -0.000202 -0.000202
2 2021-02-12  0.363          2  0.363     0.363     0.181   
3 2021-02-13  1.27           3  1.63      1.63      0.543   
4 2021-02-14  1.50           4  3.13      3.13      0.781   
5 2021-02-15  1.00           5  4.13      4.13      0.826   
6 2021-02-16 -0.458          6  3.67      4.13      0.612
```

Comment: This is beautiful thought the `foo.max` is calculated by applying `cummax` on `foo.sum` not `foo`

Comment: Why do you need to write {{col}} with two curly braces?

Comment: @skan, The curly-curly operator is rlang syntax for referring to arguments passed using nonstandard evaluation.  See `help("{{")` .

Comment: @Sinh Nguyen, Although it equals that that is not what it is dong. It applies `mx` to `foo` and where `mx` is   `mx <- function(x) cummax(cumsum(x))`

Answer (score 1):

This could be a simpler version of

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

example = tibble(
  date = today() + c(1:6),
  foo = rnorm(6), 
)

# This is your initial version of the code.
do.some.stuff <- function(data, foo.col){
  sum.col = parse_expr(paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "sum", sep="."))
  max.col = parse_expr(paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "max", sep="."))
  cnt.col = parse_expr(paste(expr_text(enexpr(foo.col)), "cnt", sep="."))
  
  select(data, date, {{ foo.col }}) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na({{ foo.col }})) %>% mutate(
      "{{ foo.col }}.cnt" := cumsum( !is.na({{ foo.col }}) ),
      "{{ foo.col }}.sum" := cumsum({{ foo.col }}),
      "{{ foo.col }}.max" := cummax( {{ sum.col }} ),
      "{{ foo.col }}.mu" :=  {{ sum.col }} / {{ cnt.col }}
    )
}

# Here is my version where foo.col is a character param
do.some.stuff_2 <- function(data, foo.col) {
  data %>% select(date, !!foo.col) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(date) & !is.na(!!foo.col)) %>%
    mutate(
      # Here as foo.col is a character to add new column just combine them together
      !!paste0(foo.col, ".cnt") := cumsum(!is.na(.data[[foo.col]])),
      !!paste0(foo.col, ".sum") := cumsum(.data[[foo.col]]),
      !!paste0(foo.col, ".max") := cummax(.data[[paste0(foo.col, ".sum")]]),
      !!paste0(foo.col, ".mu") :=  .data[[paste0(foo.col, ".sum")]] / 
                                   .data[[paste0(foo.col, ".cnt")]]
    )
}

identical(do.some.stuff(example, foo), do.some.stuff_2(example, "foo"))
```

You can learn more here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Is accessing `.data` directly not frowned upon? I am unfamiliar with R's specific conventions or etiquette but in many other languages accessing a dot or underscore variable directly would be frowned upon as an encapsulation violation. Is this type of behavior normal with dplyr?

Comment: You can check more document here. `.data` is an internal reference of `dplyr`
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html